# Fuzzy Entropy, what is the correct exponential term?

Tags: machine-learning, signal-processing, entropy, time-series, fuzzy-logic

When computing the Fuzzy Entropy measure, most works use an Exponential fuzzy function. Yet, there are two deviations between the works. For the exponential membership function, some use the term

$\exp^{-\frac{d_{ij}^n}{r}}$

so the power $n$ goes to the numerator only, while other works use

$\exp^{-\left(\frac{d_{ij}^n}{r}\right)^n}$

so the power $n$ goes to the whole fraction. Here, $r$ denotes the tolerance, and $d_{ij}$ is the maximum absolute difference calculated of the corresponding scalar components $X_i^m$, $X_j^m$, and $m$ is the length of the given window.

Which one is the correct?
Relevant works are the following, where the variation in the formula appears:
--Chen, W., Wang, Z., Xie, H., & Yu, W. (2007). Characterization of surface EMG signal based on fuzzy entropy. IEEE Transactions on neural systems and rehabilitation engineering, 15(2), 266-272.

--Chen, W., Zhuang, J., Yu, W., & Wang, Z. (2009). Measuring complexity using fuzzyen, apen, and sampen. Medical engineering & physics, 31(1), 61-68.

--Azami, H., Li, P., Arnold, S. E., Escudero, J., & Humeau-Heurtier, A. (2019). Fuzzy entropy metrics for the analysis of biomedical signals: Assessment and comparison. IEEE Access, 7, 104833-104847.

--Xiang, J., Li, C., Li, H., Cao, R., Wang, B., Han, X., & Chen, J. (2015). The detection of epileptic seizure signals based on fuzzy entropy. Journal of neuroscience methods, 243, 18-25.